# Changing the directory using os.chdir UNC filepath in python

Tags: python, operating-system, ip-address

I am attempting to change a directory via its IP address or using it's unc (as I am working in windows). This is due to the external server being mapped to different drives for different users.

Using `os.chdir(r'path\\to\remote\directory')` does not seem to work and I wonder if there are any alternatives that python doesn't hate i.e. an IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(r"\\myserver\myshare")
>>> os.getcwd()
'\\\\myserver\\myshare'
```

It's hard to tell if the `r'path\\to\remote\directory'` typo is also in your actual code and how you determined it "does not work".